# Extracting SOAP request from wsdl using wsdl4j

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

My inputs consist of a WSDL file and an operation name. I need to create a SOAP request and response XML instance after parsing the WSDL. What are my options to implement this? Which parser should I use? I tried wsdl4j. I was able to retrieve the Schema Object. But how do I convert this schema object to a SOAP Request in XML? I was not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use *soapUI* software ? I always used it in order to validate my manualy written SOAP requests (to a WSLD webservice), but it could give you the target direction

Answer (score 0):

Try membrane SOA SOAP Model library.

Example code:
http://www.membrane-soa.org/create-soap-request.htm

Note: This is not a promotion. Membrane SOA is apache 2.0 licence project and I have no relation with it, except a user. Adding URL is only for helping.